# Difficulty understanding Filtering Array - Eloquent Javascript Chapter 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am currently learning javascript with Eloquent javascript. In chapter 5 I understand the part inside the filter() function. But do not understand the line of code inside console.log :

```
    function filter(array, test) {
     let passed = [];
     for (let element of array) {
      if (test(element)) {
        passed.push(element);
    }
  }

  return passed;

}

console.log(filter(SCRIPTS, script => script.living));
```

The line I don't understand:

```
     console.log(filter(SCRIPTS, script => script.living))
     // → [{name: "Adlam", …}, …]
```

**What does** *script=>script.living* **do?** Please help.

Comment: It’s an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Your `test` parameter is invoked as a function, so passing it this particular arrow function lets `filter` know which members to retain in the filtered array by checking the truthiness of each element’s `living` property. This is a particularly weird paradigm though, considering there is a `filter()` function included in the `Array` class’ prototype already that works very much similarly to/the same as this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript everything is treated as an object. Functions are object too. So functions can be passed to other function as parameter. Those functions, which takes other functions as a parameter is called `Higher Order Function`. Here your `filter` function is a higher order function. Because it can take a function as an argument.

Now let's focus on your query. You wrote you didn't understand the following code:

```
filter(SCRIPTS, script => script.living)
```

Above piece of code can also be written as the following

```
filter(SCRIPTS, function(script) {
   return script.living 
})
```

Both of them are equivalent. The first one is called [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Arrow function is a shorter version of a regular function body.

Here, we have passed two arguments to the `filter` function. One is the `SCRIPTS` variable, and the other one is a `function` ( ***in the form of arrow function, it can be a regular function as well. Doesn't matter*** ). `filter` function will use the function-argument for its internal usage.

Comment: Thank you so so so much @AL-zami for making so simple. I wish i could vote it. But i can't because of my low reputation. :)